# Do all positive definite matrices satisfy this?

Tags: matrices

For any positive definite matrix, $A$, is the following true?

Let $A\succ 0$, then there exists some $m>0$, such that $A-mI\succeq 0$ ($A-mI$ is postive semi-definite)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, with $m$ the smallest eigenvalue. If $A$ is strictly positive definite then $m>0$, and $A-mI$ annuls the $m$ eigenvectors, so it's only semidefinite.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. $A$ is positive definite, hence $f_A$, the characteristic polynomial, has all roots real and positive. For small enough $m$, the characteristic polynomial of $A-mI$ also has only real roots, and as close to the roots of $f_A$ as one wishes. Thus $A-mI$ is also positive definite.

Comment: Minor point: The matrices $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}1&3\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ both have the exact same characteristic polynomial, but only the first one is positive definite. So having a similar characteristic polynomial is not enough to say that a matrix is positive definite.

Comment: Yes, but the RHS matrix is irrelevant in this context. All matrices involved are *symmetric*. And by definition, a symmetric matrix is positive definite if and only if all eigenvalues are positive.

Comment: The question didn't mention anything about all matrices being symmetric.

Comment: What do you mean by that? $A$ is positive definite, and in particular symmetric. Adding a scalar matrix does not change that.

Comment: It seems some definitions of positive definite require the matrix to be symmetric. The definition I learned was that $A$ is positive definite if $x^TAx \ge 0$ for all $x$ with equality iff $x = 0$ (with no requirement that $A$ be symmetric). If we require that a positive definite matrix also be symmetric, then my comments are irrelevant.

Comment: Fair enough, I guess.